# In jQuery, how to change Html Table caption based on selectino from Drop Down List

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm having trouble changing the  text of my Html table based on the **Change Event** of a drop down list.

First here's the div section with Html Table definition, plus the Drop down list:

```
    <div class="floatleft">        
    <span style="margin-left:250px;">Portfolio Filter: </span>
    <select id="drpPortFilters">
        <option>Select a portfolio filter</option>
    </select>

    <div class="PortfolioList"> <!-- PORTFOLIO TABLE ! -->
        <table id="pftable">
            <caption>Portfolio Exposures</caption>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>            
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the **jquery** document.ready() section...

Note: the "**selValue**" is indeed getting assigned. And the alert() shows me a good value !

However, '#pftable' is somehow getting lost ... meaning, this section WILL NOT change the caption !

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // Initialize Trade Contribs table (see html table below)
    var oTable = $('#contribtable').dataTable();

    // Portfolio Filters change event !!
    $('#drpPortFilters').change(function () {
        var selValue = $('#drpPortFilters option:selected').text(); //$(this).val(); 
        alert(selValue);
        $('#pftable').find("caption").text(selValue);            
    });
});
```

the strange thing is that I do succeed in changing the  text in a different section all together; that is, after I populate the Datatable() via the datatable plugin.

Perhaps datatables is getting in the way of the traditional reference using jQuery.

Any thoughts or ideas on this ???

thanks in advance.....
Bob

Comment: would be nice if you drop all this code in jsfiddle.net, so people can play and post back the solution

Answer (score 6):

My test case is here : http://live.datatables.net/oxeqij/19/edit#source

In the end, I am using scrolling in Datatables which overrides the "id" attribute of my html table "pftable". So ***I cannot*** get a handle on my Html table using **$('#pftable')**.

so the bottom line is I needed to add **class="pftable"** in my html table, then write the jQuery select as follows:

```
    $('**.pftable**').find("caption").text(selValue);
```

This finally allowed me to dynamically change the  text of my Html table.

regards.
Bob